# Automatic update in Eclipse gives error on non-installed plugin/feature

Tags: eclipse

When trying a 'Check for updates' in Eclipse Juno updates are found, but errors prevent continuing the installation: *The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.* Those details are:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.2.20130211-1820 (epp.package.jee 1.5.2.20130211-1820)
  Software currently installed: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 2.2.0.201211211917 (oracle.eclipse.tools.juno.weblogic.feature.group 2.2.0.201211211917)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Workbench 3.104.0.v20121219-151754 (org.eclipse.ui.workbench 3.104.0.v20121219-151754)
    Eclipse Workbench 3.104.0.v20121114-140926 (org.eclipse.ui.workbench 3.104.0.v20121114-140926)
    Eclipse Workbench 3.103.0.v20120530-1824 (org.eclipse.ui.workbench 3.103.0.v20120530-1824)
    Eclipse Workbench 3.103.1.v20120906-120042 (org.eclipse.ui.workbench 3.103.1.v20120906-120042)
    Eclipse Workbench 3.104.0.v20130204-164612 (org.eclipse.ui.workbench 3.104.0.v20130204-164612)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.2.20130211-1820 (epp.package.jee 1.5.2.20130211-1820)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.5.2.20130211-1820]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle Common Tools 5.2.0.201211211917 (oracle.eclipse.tools.common 5.2.0.201211211917)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench [3.8.0,3.104.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 2.2.0.201211211917 (oracle.eclipse.tools.juno.weblogic.feature.group 2.2.0.201211211917)
    To: oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic [5.2.0.201211211917]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 5.2.0.201211211917 (oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic 5.2.0.201211211917)
    To: bundle oracle.eclipse.tools.common [5.2.0,5.3.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.5.2.20130211-1820 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20130211-1820)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.2.2.v20130129-152330-7IARAABrMQkGSvMgQnUlz-DQz00h)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.workbench [3.104.0.v20130204-164612]
```

The *Installation History* shows no installed Oracle software in the Current Installation, but previous configurations include Oracle WebLogic Server Tools and/or Oracle WebLogic Scripting Tools.

Any suggestions to make Eclipse update itself again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current versions of Eclipse Juno and WebLogic Server Tools are incompatible at the moment. See the [answer](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10901235#10901235) I got on an Oracle discussion forum for details.

Update: the WebLogic Server Tools has been updated and can now be installed on the current Eclipse Juno version.